# Linked list in c reset in the middle of code

Tags: c, linked-list

I am working on a code that uses 2 linked lists. the first one is pixels and the second is a list of group of pixels (let call them flake).

here is my code, only the structs, and the functions, and I marked the place where my list suddenly reset and I don't know why. Help me please, thank you!!

```
typedef struct { //pixel's coordinates
    int x;
    int y;
}co_t;

typedef struct pixel { //list of pixels
    co_t p;
    struct pixel* next;
}pix_t;

typedef struct flake { //flake's detailed list extructed of bmp
    int size; //the number of pixels that combine the flake
    co_t p1;
    co_t p2;
    pix_t* pArr; //list of flake pixels
    struct flake* next;
}flakeList_t;

//prototypes:
flakeList_t* insert_top_flake(int y, int x,flakeList_t* head);
flakeList_t* scan_list(pix_t* mainlist, flakeList_t* flakelist);
```

Functions:

```
flakeList_t* scan_list(pix_t*mainlist, flakeList_t* flakelist) {
        if (flakelist->pArr == NULL) { 
            flakelist->pArr = insert_top(mainlist->p.y, mainlist->p.x, flakelist);
            //return head; //return mean - next pixel
        }
        else { 
            while (mainlist != NULL) {
                while (mainlist != NULL && flakelist->pArr != NULL) {
                    int d1, d2;
                    d1 = abs(mainlist->p.x - flakelist->pArr->p.x);
                    d2 = abs(mainlist->p.y - flakelist->pArr->p.y);
                    if (d1 > 1 || d2 > 1) { 
                        flakelist->pArr = flakelist->pArr->next;
                    }
                    else if (d1 <= 1 || d2 <= 1) { 
                    flakelist->pArr = insert_top(mainlist->p.y, mainlist->p.x, flakelist->pArr);
                    mainlist = mainlist->next;
                    
                    }
                    **//in this point the linked list reset!! until here it works great\\**

                }
                if (mainlist != NULL) {
                    pix_t* ptr_arr = NULL; //new linked list of pixel
                    pix_t* head_arr = NULL;
                    ptr_arr = malloc(sizeof(pix_t));
                    ptr_arr->p.x = mainlist->p.x;
                    ptr_arr->p.y = mainlist->p.y;
                    ptr_arr->next = NULL; //until here
                    flakeList_t* new_node = NULL;
                    new_node = (flakeList_t*)malloc(sizeof(flakeList_t));
                    new_node->p1.x = 0;
                    new_node->p2.x = 0;
                    new_node->p1.y = 0;
                    new_node->p2.y = 0;
                    new_node->size = 18;
                    new_node->pArr = ptr_arr;
                    new_node->next = flakelist;
                    flakelist = new_node;
                    //flakelist = insert_top_flake(mainlist->p.y, mainlist->p.x, flakelist);
                    mainlist = mainlist->next;
                }
            }   
        }
        return flakelist;
    } 

pix_t* insert_top(int y, int x, pix_t* head) {
    pix_t* new_node;
    new_node = (pix_t*)malloc(sizeof(pix_t));
    new_node->p.x = x;
    new_node->p.y = y;
    new_node->next = head;
    head = new_node;
    return head;
}
flakeList_t* insert_top_flake(int y, int x, flakeList_t* head) {
    flakeList_t* new_node = NULL;
    new_node = (flakeList_t*)malloc(sizeof(flakeList_t));
    pix_t* ptr_arr = NULL; //new linked list of pixel
    pix_t* head_arr = NULL;
    ptr_arr = malloc(sizeof(pix_t));
    ptr_arr->p.x = x;
    ptr_arr->p.y = y;
    ptr_arr->next = NULL; //until here
    new_node->p1.x = 0;
    new_node->p2.x = 0;
    new_node->p1.y = 0;
    new_node->p2.y = 0;
    new_node->size = 18;
    new_node->pArr = ptr_arr;
    new_node->next = head;

    head = new_node;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Can you precise what you want to achieve with `flakelist->pArr = flakelist->pArr->next;
` ? Using the pointers array of a struct/object as a pointer index seems not right...

Comment: @Dar Looani - code is incomplete